# Any AppCompat style property to customize border style for AppCompatButton?

Tags: android, button, styles, android-appcompat

We can construct and customize border of buttons using drawables.but i just want to know is there any alternative way to set border to new `AppCompatButton` using new `AppCompat` libraries through styles or something ? I have surfed for it and i haven't found any documents.So developers, let me know if any tricks to do that.

And problem is the default behavior of `AppCompatButton` will change if we were setting `android:background` property and we may need to provide click states too while the `AppCompatButton` have the click effect by default.

Comment: Making a `selector.xml` and using it in `drawable` is the classic way. Don't need any other style because you can customize your `selector.xml` as you desired.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your opinion `#Clairvoyant` .But what i felt is Android is updating steadily and they might brought any advanced solution to make it more sizlng.Oki, thank's for your time.

Comment: @Clairvoyant And also there is one problem if following the way of drawables.the default behavior of `AppCompactButton` will change if we were setting `android:background` property and we may need to provide click states too while the `AppCompactButton` have by default.

Comment: As i said you can customize as you desired so obviously it would change background property and states depending on the `selector xml`.

Comment: In fact i need to change only border without affecting any other feature and i know it's not possible.So that am seeking for new solution to add only border.that's why i have asked about the `AppCompat` feature and i realized the chances are less.let's see.